# Re-use DOTween tweeners

Tags: unity, dotween

I am using DOTween, and I want to create a tweener, store it, and re-use it in the future several times.

```
    Tweener playerMoveUpTweener = player.transform.DOLocalMove(new Vector3(0,100,0), 0.5f, true);
    playerMoveUpTweener.SetEase (Ease.Linear);
    playerMoveUpTweener.SetRelative (true);
    playerMoveUpTweener.SetRecyclable (true);
    playerMoveUpTweener.OnComplete(() => {
        // some stuff
    });
```

But, in the future, I can't seem to be able to use it:

```
playerMoveUpTweener.Play();
```

Won't work. Not even with `Rewind()` or `Restart()`.

Is it actually possible to re-use this same tweener?

Comment: I'm looking at the source code here:  https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/tree/develop/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween    --  And there doesn't seem to be any easy way to reset a tween.  Do you really need to use such a bloated tween engine?

Comment: @Jon well, I just happen to be used to it. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Based on the source code, it appears you may need to call Tweener.Setup()  -- however, I am unsure.

Comment: @Jon I don't think I can call that. Looks like an internal method and can't be accessed from my scripts.

Comment: The reset command says this:   // Doesn't reset active state, activeId and despawned, since those are only touched by TweenManager  -- Doesn't reset default values since those are set when Tweener.Setup is called.

You may have to do all this stuff manually -- Really not sure why this lib doesn't include a proper reset.

Comment: Might be worth your time to contact the developer and ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tween is killed after it is completed, unless autokill is set to false.

```
playerMoveUpTweener.SetAutoKill(false);
```

Then use restart to play it again.

```
playerMoveUpTweener.Restart();
```